# plone.app.multilingual without language root folder?

Tags: plone, multilingual, linguaplone

Is it possible to use plone.app.multilingual without language root folders (e.g. en, de)? At the moment we are using LinguaPlone and we don't want to change the structure of our site.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I think that out of the box it is not possible to use PAM without the root folders, e.g. if you change the language of an item it is moved to the corresponding root folder.